# How to run index.html file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have an ASP.NET vNext project with the web start template. I've added a new html file and I wish to run it. However when I go to localhost:1111/index.html I get 404 error. Is there a special configuration in the grunt file?

[image]

Comment: How is your IIS configured? are you using IIS express? (the one that comes along with VS), or do you have a full IIS install?

Comment: If this is a vNext project, you should be able to click the arrow to the right of the Start (F5) button and click Internet Explorer (or another browser) and it should open up in that browser. If not, try simply right-clicking the Index file and selecting Run (without debugging) or something like that.

Comment: The IIS is IIS Express and when I click on 'run' I get the home view of the basic web application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML file needs to be inside the root of wwwroot folder. You can move the file manually inside the folder and then edit it from inside wwwroot folder. Alternatively set up a Grunt task to copy it to the wwwroot folder using [grunt-contrib-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy).

Depending on how you are hosting the project you will then have to enable static files. One way is to use the AspNet Static Files package.

In the project.json add with the beta version you are using (it is there by default in some project templates)

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
```

In the Startup.cs tell the app to use static files (this is also added by default in some templates)

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Then this should work...

Also the wwwroot folder is just the default in the starter template, you can change this by looking in the project.json file and changing the webroot property

```
"webroot": "wwwroot",
```

In your case you could change it to "." which would set the webroot to be the project folder but I think it is much better to have the "wwwroot" folder which makes it easier to control what can be accessed statically. If you use any languages which needs to be processed into static files, for example SASS and TypeScript, then it is a nice workflow to have the source files outside the webroot and then process them and set the destination to the webroot.